# Add an initial value to RX Stream / IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a method that returns a filtered RX stream as an Iobservable :

```
public IObservable<Price> LivePrices(Instrument instrumentDetails)
        {
            return _priceObserver.Stream
                .Where(o => o.Symbol == instrumentDetails.Symbol )
                .Select(o => GetPrice(o, instrumentDetails));
        }
```

The issue is that the stream doesnt change very often for certain values so I need to initialise it with a first value

How can I do that? I am reading that a `Subject` can be both an observer and an observable. So I think I need to somehow subscribe to it as a `Subject`, add the first message in the stream, then set it to what it is now. But cant figure out how to do that

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `StartWith`?

```
public IObservable<FxDeal> LiveRates(NegotiationDetails negotiation)
{   
    var obs = _ratesObserver.Stream
        .Where(o => o.BaseCurrency == negotiation.Base && o.TermsCurrency == negotiation.Terms)
        .Select(o => GetFxDeal(o, negotiation));

    return condition ? obs.StartWith(new FxDeal()) : obs;
}
```

Comment: oh wow, I had no idea that method existed. it looks like exactly what I need. There is no condition though so presumably I can just do :
obs.StartWith(new FxDeal());
return obs;

Comment: and it will add the first value, then the subsequent stream?

Comment: Yes. It will immediately push that value whenever something subscribes, followed by the rest of your stream.

Comment: Try `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).StartWith(-1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: hey @asti , I couldnt get it to work. think it might be because the method is async. have posted another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339649/rx-startwith-in-async-method-not-applying-the-starting-value

Comment: @ChrisCa Seems you figured it out. In my example, I return `obs.StartWith`, so it has an effect.