# Rx StartWith in async method not applying the starting value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to inject an initial value into an RX stream using the `StartWith` method:

```
public async Task<IObservable<Price>) Stream(Instrument instrumentDetails)
{
    var initialPrice = await _svc.GetSomeInitialPrice();

    var stream = _priceObserver.Stream
        .Where(o => o.Symbol == instrumentDetails.Symbol)
        .Select(o => GetPrice(o, instrumentDetails));

    stream.StartWith(initialPrice);

    return stream;
}
```

however, the method is async due to the call to get the initial value. and it needs to be async all the way through this call stack anyway

I am finding the value is never added to the start. I just get the rest of the stream

if I `await` the `StartWith` method, it never returns

any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods on the `IObservable` don't modify the underlying object - they return a new one. `stream.StartWith(initialPrice)` returns a new observable which you ignore, it doesn't do anything to `stream`.

You should write it like this:

```
stream = stream.StartWith(initialPrice);
```

Or:

```
var stream = _priceObserver.Stream
    .Where(o => o.Symbol == instrumentDetails.Symbol)
    .Select(o => GetPrice(o, instrumentDetails))
    .StartWith(initialPrice);
```

Side note: if you await an observable, it will wait until the observable is complete, i.e. when it emits all its values and calls its `OnComplete` method. You should usually await an observable, which you know will emit only 1 value and then complete (e.g. a request to a remote server), because awaiting it will return only the last emitted value. So if your `stream` is expected to continuously emit values, it makes no sense to await it.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off avoiding mixing of `Task<>` and `Observable<>` like you're doing. If you can, just stick with `IObservable<>`.

In your case it's pretty easy.

Just try this:

```
public IObservable<Price> Stream(Instrument instrumentDetails)
    =>
        Observable
            .FromAsync(() => _svc.GetSomeInitialPrice())
            .SelectMany(x =>
                _priceObserver
                    .Stream
                    .Where(o => o.Symbol == instrumentDetails.Symbol)
                    .Select(o => GetPrice(o, instrumentDetails))
                    .StartWith(x));
```

I've tested this with a basic bit of code and it works just fine. It also ensures that new subscribers will any new values that `_svc.GetSomeInitialPrice()` might produce over time.